# PDF: Unable to highlight selected word from UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uiwebview

I am doing book reading app. I am displaying every PDF in `UIWebView`. I am trying to highlight a selected word. But I failed. Then, I unable to get selected string from PDF too.

**My Code:**

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("window.getSelection().toString();")
```

The above code working fine, when `UIWebView` content is **HTML**. But, failed in **PDF**.
Kindly guide me, how to highlight a selected text colour?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that you'd ever be able to get content of selections like that within a UIWebView since the Javascript would only work on HTML. A third party library would probably give you the functionality you're after, and this one looks pretty good: https://github.com/vfr/Reader

Comment: I having that vfr. In that coding also, user unable to select a text. Only hyper links are working. Thank u @alexpls